# Process tags in description , Android, RSS, XML parser

Tags: android, xml, rss

I have a little problem with my Android RSS reader. I am using XML parser to get tags from RSS feed, but sometimes, in description, i have many of them - like, `<description> <img src="some random url"><table...`, e.t.c. I want to process them, esp. the IMG tag.How can i procees all of them (becuase now i have a bunch of unparsed code in description).Here is a read function from my parser class.

```
   private List<RssItem> readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "rss");
    String title = null;
    String link = null;
    String description = null;
    String pubDate = null;
    String url = null;
    List<RssItem> items = new ArrayList<RssItem>();
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        if (name.equals("title")) {
            title = readTitle(parser);
        } else if (name.equals("link")) {
            link = readLink(parser);
        }
        else if(name.equals("description")) {
            description = readDescription(parser);
    }
        else if(name.equals("pubDate")) {
            pubDate = readPubDate(parser);
        }

        if (title != null && link != null) {
            RssItem item = new RssItem(title, link, description, pubDate, url);
            items.add(item);
            title = null;
            link = null;
            description = null;
            pubDate = null;
            url = null;
        }
    }
    return items;
}


    private String readDescription(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException{
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "description");
    String description = readText(parser);
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "description");
    return description;
}

    private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    String result = "";
    if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
        result = parser.getText();
        parser.nextTag();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue, part of solution you can take description as a string and pass it to method that return String array to represent parameters. jsoup library could help to extract image link. still doesn't know if it could extract other parameters.
here is what I did so far.

```
public String[] stripHtml(String html) {
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
        String picLink = document.select("img").first().attr("src");
        String result = Html.fromHtml(html).toString();
        result = result.substring(0, result.indexOf('['));
        String[] linkAndDescription = {picLink, result};

        return linkAndDescription;
    }
```

**EDIT**
this is the full solution for my situation, I want to parse image link and description text.

```
public String[] stripHtml(String html) {
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
        //piclink
        String picLink = document.select("img").first().attr("src");
        //description
        String text = document.select("p").first().text();
        text = text.substring(0, text.indexOf('['));
        String[] linkAndDescription = {picLink, text};

        return linkAndDescription;
    }
```